# Show that this limit exists

Tags: analysis

Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ and $x_0 \in (a,b)$, Suppose for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that
$$\left| f(x) - f(y) \right| < \epsilon \hspace{3cm} \forall \space\ 0 < \left| x - x_{0} \right|, \left| y - x_{0} \right| < \delta $$

Show that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to x_{0}} f(x)$ exists.

My attempt:

Proof: We need to show $\forall \epsilon > 0 \space\ \exists \delta > 0$ such that 
$$0 < |x - x_{0}| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - L | < \epsilon$$
where $L = \displaystyle\lim_{x \to x_{0}} f(x)$. Then,
\begin{align*}
|f(x) - L| &= |f(x) - f(y) + f(y) - L| \\
&\leq |f(x) - f(y)| + |f(y) - L| \\
&< \epsilon + |f(y) - L| \\
\end{align*}

Not really sure how to use what I am given to make a relation with $|f(y) - L| < \epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)$ doesn't exist. Now let $A=\displaystyle\liminf_{x\to x_0} f(x)$ and $B=\displaystyle\limsup_{x\to x_0} f(x)$. So $B-A>0$ (we can assume that both are finite, the infinite case is trivial). Let $\epsilon = \frac{B-A}{4}$. Now $\exists \delta > 0$ s.t. $\forall \space\ 0 < \left| x - x_{0} \right|, \left| y - x_{0} \right| < \delta $ we have $\left| f(x) - f(y) \right| < \epsilon$. But now we can find $a,b\in B(x_o,\frac{\delta}{2})$ s.t. $|f(a)-A|<\epsilon$ and $|f(b)-B|<\epsilon$. But now $|f(b)-f(a)|\gt B-A-2\epsilon=2\epsilon\gt\epsilon$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Consider $x_n=x_0-\frac 1n.$ Consider $\delta>0$ and $y$ satisfying $0<|y-x_0|<\delta.$ Since $|x_n-x_0|<\delta$ for $n$ big enough we have that $$|f(x_n)-f(y)|<\epsilon,$$ from where we have that $(f(x_n))$ is a bounded sequence. So, it has a convergent subsequence. Call its limit $L.$ We will show that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=L.$

Use the inequality

$$||f(x_n)-L|-|f(y)-L||\le |f(x_n)-f(y)|<\epsilon$$ to conclude.